# org mode not showing all the text in my file?

Tags: org-mode, buffers, outline-mode, visibility

I am new to Emacs and struggling to learn it.

I have a `test.org` file:

```
* Heading

** Sub-Heading

*** Third-level
```

When I open the file, the buffer just displays:

```
* Heading...
```

Where did all the rest of my text go?  How do I see what else is in that file?

Comment: You can use [Tab] to expand headings when your cursor is on them, and [Shift] + [Tab] to cycle the visibility of all headings in your file at the same time. These don't modify anything, they're just visual things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Showing just a visible summary of the buffer is one of the
features of `org-mode`, which is, in turn, built on top
of
[`outline-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Outline-Mode.html).

The idea is to get a lot of the details out of the way so you can
get an overview of the buffer contents, and then drill down into
the relevant sections by unfolding/showing the contents while
leaving everything else folded/hidden.

Take a look at the `org-mode` manual node
on
[visibility cycling](http://orgmode.org/manual/Visibility-cycling.html) to
see how to use this feature.

You can, of course, customize the level of visibility that
`org-mode` uses at start up.  For the default value, you can use
the
[`customize` machinery](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Easy-Customization.html) to
set the value of `org-startup-folded`, or you can set it by hand
in your `init` file.  Here's the docstring for that variable
(which you can view by hitting `C-h v org-startup-folded`, which
calls `describe-variable` on that variable):

> org-startup-folded is a variable defined in ‘org.el’.
> Its value is t
>
> Documentation:
> Non-nil means entering Org-mode will switch to OVERVIEW.
> This can also be configured on a per-file basis by adding one of
> the following lines anywhere in the buffer:
>
> #+STARTUP: fold              (or ‘overview’, this is equivalent)
>
> #+STARTUP: nofold            (or ‘showall’, this is equivalent)
>
> #+STARTUP: content
>
> #+STARTUP: showeverything
>
> By default, this option is ignored when Org opens agenda files
> for the first time.  If you want the agenda to honor the startup
> option, set ‘org-agenda-inhibit-startup’ to nil.
>
> You can customize this variable.

So you could put `(setq org-startup-folded t)` in your `init` file
if you wanted to fold everything up by default, or `(setq org-startup-folded nil)` if you want it to show everything at
startup. Note that the value of this variable has to be a *symbol*, not a string, so for values other than `t` or `nil`, use e.g. `(setq org-startup-folded 'content)` or `(setq org-startup-folded 'showeverything)` - the quote is important.

As the docstring implies, you can also set visibility on a
file-by-file basis by putting something like

```
#+STARTUP: fold
```

or

```
#+STARTUP: showeverything
```

at the beginning or end of the file.  (Note that you would need
the `#` to line up with the leftmost column; don't indent it or
`org-mode` may not understand what you're doing.)